# Using Firebase Location Coordinates - Cannot Load Annotations

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, mapkit, core-location

I am currently trying to plug in a users coordinates from firebase into my function that will then represent these coordinates on my map. I don't know if this has something to do with me changing the coordinates from a string to a double.

An issue could also be that swift is not recognizing mapView as a part of the viewcontroller's class. I used my @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView! as a replacement in hopes that the annotations would show.

```
 func retrieveUsers(){
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            let users = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            self.user.removeAll()
            for (_,value) in users {
                if let uid = value["uid"] as? String {
                    if uid != Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid {
                        let userToShow = User()
                        if let fullName = value["full name"] as? String, let imagePath = value["urlToImage"] as? String
                            ,let snap = snapshot.value as? [String: Any],
                            let userLongitude = Double(snap["long"] as! String),
                            let userLatitude = Double(snap["lat"] as! String)


                        {

                            let otherUserLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLatitude, longitude: userLongitude)


                            let userAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                            userAnnotation.coordinate = otherUserLocation
                            userAnnotation.title = fullName


                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.map.addAnnotation(userAnnotation)
                            }




                        }
```

Comment: you are asking two questions at once here.  the problem is EITHER in how you retrieve the data from firebase OR in how you create the annotation.  So check to see that you're getting valid Lat/Lon values when you read them in, and try hard-coding a position to see if you can create the annotation.  Then you will have one problem left to solve, not a combination of two

Comment: Hi Russel I did hard code the annotation and it works properly.

Comment: OK - then the problem is in how you are loading from firebase - check that what you are returning as 'userLongitude' and 'userLatitude' is what you are expecting to see

Comment: Thank you! Do you think it could be do to uploading the coodinates as strings in firebase and then trying to convert them to doubles?

Comment: Yes.  You should be able to convert them to what you need, but it must be easier to store the data in the form you will be using it